# Add Multiple Sheets into Exported Spreadsheet in SAP Fiori

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

Is it possible to add multiple sheets into the exported Spreadsheet in Smart Table in SAP Fiori?

I came across the following information in the API Library:

> The sap.ui.export.Spreadsheet library always exports the actual data
> to the main sheet of the Office Open XML spreadsheet but it can also
> add an additional sheet for meta information. The consuming
> applications can then assign their own specific names to both sheets.

It seems that `context` information can be added using the `metainfo` property. Does this imply that only one additional sheet can be added to the XLSX file?
[image]

Find [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZdBsdmCMntxrFBnS) project.
Please help.

Comment: right. The additional sheet is just for meta info, not the business data. But you are exporting a single table, why would you need multiple sheets?

Comment: Thank you @krisho . I was searching for a way using which we can configure multiple sheets using some array like we configure the first additional sheet. I am not looking to add table data to the additional sheets, I will have other dependent data for the additional sheets.